# How to load/include an visualforce page in modal box?

Tags: custom-button, visualforce, iframe, modal

I create a modal on a new button with javascript :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

function insertScript(){ 

var box = new SimpleDialog("hersh"+Math.random(), true); 
parent.box = box; 
box.setTitle("Create new Order"); 
box.createDialog(); 
box.setWidth(350); 
box.setContentInnerHTML("<apex:page standardController='Quote'><apex:outputPanel><center><apex:iframe src='OPDevisEN?id={!Quote.Id}' /></center><p>Ceci est un exemple de texte.</p></apex:outputPanel><button class='btn' onclick='window.parent.box.hide(); return false;'>Annuler</button></apex:page>"); 
box.setupDefaultButtons(); 
box.show(); 
} 
insertScript();
```

The modal works, but how can i load my VF page in it with an iframe ?
Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something my friend wrote 
http://forceapp.blogspot.in/2015/08/custom-button-popup-on-detail-page.html

hope this helps.Do let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want jQuery. This is my working code :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')}

var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/OPDevisEN")}'+'?id={!Quote.Id}' ;



function insertScript(){ 

var box = new SimpleDialog("Test", true); 
parent.box = box; 
box.setTitle("Create new Order"); 
box.createDialog(); 
box.setWidth(800); 
box.setContentInnerHTML("<apex:page standardController='Quote'><div><center><p>Ceci est un exemple de texte.</p><button class='btn' onclick='window.parent.box.hide(); return false;'>Fermer</button></center></div><div><center><iframe style='width:100%;height:500px;' id='iframeContentId' src='" + iframe_url + "' frameborder='0' marginheight='50' marginwidth='10' scrolling='no' /></center></div></apex:page>"); 
box.setupDefaultButtons(); 
box.show(); 
} 
insertScript();
```